# Historically, who realized the inverse function theorem could be proved with the use of contraction mappings?

Tags: intuition, lipschitz-functions, inverse-function-theorem

Historically, who realized the inverse function theorem could be proved with the use of contraction mappings? And moreover, how was the connection between contraction mappings and the inverse function theorem made?

I understand the outline of the proof, and I can see it logically flows very easily from the mean value theorem and a few other basic multivariable analysis principles. But I am having trouble seeing how I could have ever 'invented it myself'. How could you know a priori that a clever choice of definition for $\phi_y(x)$ will simultaneously give me a contraction mapping and that $\phi_y(x) = x$ would imply $f(x) = y$.

I feel like there is some standard technique and way of thinking about fixedpoints (or maybe even just smooth functions) that I'm missing.